# How to upgrade to Disco with limited /boot partition size?

Tags: boot, partitioning, 19.04, lvm, do-release-upgrade

My bionic (18.04) install has a very small /boot size because Ubuntu used to suggest that for some reason. Running the `sudo do-release-upgrade` the upgrade stops saying that I need to make space for 300+ MB on /boot, but it's not that big in the first place:

```
$ df -T | grep -v tmpfs
Filesystem               Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/kubuntu-root ext4      914G  702G  166G  81% /
/dev/sda1                ext2      228M   86M  131M  40% /boot
/dev/sdb2                ext4      823G  404G  377G  52% /media/myusername/WDblue2TBbkup
/dev/sdb1                ext4     1012G  574G  386G  60% /media/myusername/WDblue2TBmedia
```

Resizing is difficult because the boot lies at the front of the disk and theres an LVM2 partition there holding the rest of the OS & data under the root directory (`/`) in a ext4 filesystem.

Any advice about how to proceed?

I'm considering

- **finding the kernel that disco would use and seeing if I can install that prior to running the upgrade**.

I've also upgraded in the past by simply

- **changing my `apt/sources.list`**, and associated files, to point to the later versions repos; that's a possibility too.

Strikes me at some point I'll need to fix the small `/boot`

- **can I perhaps make a new boot directory as part of the LVM** and just wipe the old boot partition?

Hints, tips, suggestions, solutions all gratefully received.

Edit: I've just found the exact out-of-space message in my clipboard entries, it is "`The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 319 M free space on disk '/boot'.`".

Answer (score -1):

Well, I would try this commands: 
*) uname -a  ==>  to write down latest "default" kernel version.
*) In your "df" command - change it twice ; a) df -hT ; b) df -HT and see the difference. 
*) Do this : "du -sch /boot/* | sort -hr" . This will show you if you have multiple kernels installed. If you are, UNinstall all but "uname -a" kernel in Package Manager. I myself am using Synaptic for this....

Comment: Thanks Jovan, I'm familiar with cleaning kernels, I have two installed, ordinarily I remove the backup kernel before installing a new one and there is enough space to do that -- but the update to Disco tells me it needs more free space (319MB, see update to the question) than the partition has in total (228MB) so just moving kernels around won't do it. I'd have to remove all current kernels which is too risky really. I'm not sure why the upgrade would need so much space relative.

Answer (score -1):

I just did this:

```
sudo mkdir /boot-new
sudo cp --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps --recursive /boot/ --target-directory=/boot-new # copy boot to a new directory in the root lvm
```

that puts everything in /boot-new/boot, so I needed to `sudo mv -r /boot-new/boot /boot-new/`. To check I then did:

```
sudo diff -s -r /boot /boot-new/
```

which confirms it all copied correctly (`-s` spams the console telling you each file is identical).

Then I did:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab{,.$(date +%F)}
```

Then

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

Edited out the previous `/boot` line by commenting it with a `#`.

Finally:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then rebooted, all is well and I can now update. Really I should probably have just taken the plunge but I didn't know for sure that GRUB was going to handle the LVM2 volume properly.